# Matrix with non-one terms on the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

I'm wondering what you call a square matrix that's a diagonal matrix, but isn't the  identity matrix?

Orthogonal Matrix definition:

$$A^T A = I$$

What about an "Almost Orthogonal Matrix":

$$A^T A = (any\ diagonal\ except\ I?)$$

it has orthogonal rows and columns, its just not normalized...

what do you call that matrix?

Comment: A diagonal matrix.

Comment: but an identity matrix is also diagonal..  I want all diagonal matrices except  indentity

Comment: Call it 'non-identity diagonal matrix'.